# finding and angle and coordinate point

Tags: trigonometry

"For a given angle $θ$ and a circle of radius $r$ and center $(h,k)$, recall that we can determine the Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ of the point on the circle determined by $θ$ and $r$, where

$x=h+rcosθ,y=k+rsinθ$"

can someone explain this in simple language to me please? i'm actually a programmer and i'm stumped on this... i know thats sad. technology is not our friend all the time. years of computers and lack of pencil and paper math have made me dumm.. dum.. doom...... stupid :) lol

thanks
brian

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  It would be good to know where you are starting from.  Do you know the general equation of a circle?

Answer (score 3):

Try this and, if you do not understand any particular part, then ask in the comments

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$(r \cos \theta)^2 + (r \sin \theta)^2 = r^2\cos^2 \theta + r^2\sin^2 \theta = r^2(\cos^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta) = r^2$ so a point with coordinates $(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$ lies on the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$.  To shift this circle away from the origin we use $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$ thus $x-h=r\cos \theta$ and $y-k=r\sin \theta$ lie on the shifted circle.  From there you just add $h$ to both sides of the first equation and $k$ to both sides of the second equation to get the solution you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you draw a circle of radius 1 with centre at (0,0). Any point on this circle will have coordinate $(cos{\theta}, sin{\theta})$. where $\theta$ starts at 0 on the positive x axis (so you are at (1, 0) and goes round anticlockwise through 360 until you are back at (1, 0).
For a circle of radius r you will have coordinate $(rcos{\theta}, rsin{\theta})$.
If the centre of the circle moves to (h, k) then the coordinates of the points on the circle will translate by the same amount to $(h+rcos{\theta},k+rsin{\theta})$